# A product of two subgroups with a certain property

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and let $H$ and $A$ be two subgroups of $G$ such that $H<A$.
Now suppose that there exists a subgroup $N$ of $G$ such that $H$ is a characteristic normal subgroup of $N$. Is the product $NA$ a subgroup of $G$?

Comment: No. Let $N$ and $A$ be any subgroups of any group $G$ such that $NA$ is not a subgroup of $G$, and let $H$  be the trivial subgroup of $G$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. (Briefly, the binary icosahedral group will give a counterexample.)

Take $G=\text{SL}(2,5)$.

Let $N$ be a Sylow-2-subgroup; this is quaternion of order $8$. Let $H$ be the centre of $G$. Let $A$ be a subgroup of order $10$ containing $H$, the pre-image of a Sylow-5-subgroup of $\text{PSL}(2,5)$.

If $NA$ is a subgroup its order will be $|N||A|/|N\cap A|=40$, and it contains the centre. Its image in $\text{PSL}(2,5)$ will be of order $20$. But $\text{PSL}(2,5)\simeq A_5$ has no such subgroup.

Answer (score 2):

You can build an example starting with any group containing two subgroups whose product is not a subgroup.

Let $L$ be a finite group containing two subgroups $S, A$ such that $S A$ is not a subgroup.

Let $H$ be a finite group of order coprime to the order of $S$.

In the direct product $G = H \times L$, consider the subgroup $N = H S = H \times S$.

Then $H$ is clearly characteristic in $N$, but $N A = H S A$ is not a subgroup of $G$. If it were, then also the image $S A$ of $N A$ under the natural epimorphism $G \to L$ with kernel $H$ would be a subgroup of $L$, against the assumption.